# How to get only specific read data from firebase for a particular child node

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Heyy Developers, I'm creating a Tv series app in which I store Season no, episodes no, etc. For storing data I'm using Firebase realtime database but I want to retrive Season no only in a recyclerview when I click on a specific series but database returns every season no in my recycelrview for every series, for ex. In my database I store two series Money heist and Moon knight and each have 2 and 3 seasons respectively, but when I click on Money heist it returns me combine of both series that is 5 instead it should return 2 only and same thing happens for moon knight.
I'm using recyclerview to show  series list by reading data from realtime database.

```
  "MONEY HEIST ": {    <------- I'm creating this series name node 
                                                programatically

    "Season": {
      "Season 1": {
        "Episodes": {
          "episode no": 1
        },
        "season_no": "Season 1"
      },
      "Season 2": {
        "Episodes": {
          "Episode 2": "jsdfjfjskkshfksdfksdfsdsfsdjfljforhfvbincieefnlsclsladlasdlefiowfjkdnckcdbebckwcnkwhefksdnfksdnfksdfnksnfksdnskdfnksdnfksndfksndfksndfksndfdfsdfndsfns,dnf"
        },
        "season_no": "Season 2"
      }
    }
  },
  "MOON KNIGHT ": {
    "Season": {
      "Season 1": {
        "Episodes": {
          "Episode 1": ""
        },
        "season_no": "Season 1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to show only season no of specific series name means if I click on Moon knight it should show only its seasons and not of others and same for others.

So far i tried this method to retrive data from firebase,

```
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {



                for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren())
                {

                    for (DataSnapshot pc : ds.getChildren())
                    {


                            for (DataSnapshot bi : pc.getChildren()) {
                                season_number number = bi.getValue(season_number.class);
                                details.add(number);


                        }
                    }






                }
                series = new Adapter_ofreal_season(details);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(series);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

And im creating Series name node programatically..

Comment: You could split the collection up. So that you have two documents (serie "money Heist" and "moon Knight"). Then you dont have to worry about getting the details about a different series.

Comment: Collection....but im using realtime database....any help in this ??

Answer (score 0):

If you make your Firebase look like this:

[image: FireBase structure]

so every serie will have its own document within the collection `Series`
And every serie has a collection of `Seasons`, which has `Episodes` and so on.

Then when you just want to have all data of "MONEY HEIST"

you can do:

```java
docRef = db.collection("series").document("MONEY HEIST");

docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            // Document found
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            Log.d(TAG, "document data: " + document.getData());
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "failed: ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

[source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document)
edit: 
Also, you could map the results of your call to an Object. In this way you can easily use the data in your program. This is done with the `toObject()` call. Keep in mind that then your Firebase document and Object have the same naming and no-argument constructors (You can read more about this [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#custom_objects)).

Comment: I got your suggestion but if I follow your way then I will get only one document from this code `docRef = db.collection("series").document("MONEY HEIST"); ` and then I have to do it for every series list which will be a bad idea to implement , I want for example , I a user click on Moon knight he/she will get its seasons and episodes and same for everyrthing but brother I have a huge amount of list of series, I can't write code for everyseries....

Comment: Well you have a recyclerview, to fill that you can make a call like `getSeries()` this will give you a list of all the series you have (`db.collection("series").get()`). Then you can append all the items to the recyclerviewer. And when you click a item you can use te name already in recyclerviewer to make a new call to FireStore, or even a function (`getAllOfSerie(<String serie>)`). `db.collection("series").document("<name from recyclerviewer>")`

Comment: Thank you for your help @stefen de kraker but somehow I manged to solve my problem from RTDB.  :)